# How to create a lossy JPEG 2000 sequence with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg2000

I’d like to convert a movie to a lossy JPEG 2000 sequence with FFmpeg using `libopenjpeg`. I found `-compression_level` to control the compression but I‘m looking for a kind of variable bitrate control like `-crf`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think J2K has any quality controls like that. CRF is not an FFmpeg thing, the actual encoders need to support it. libx264 or libx265 have it, but I don't know any image encoders that work like that.